# What is the difference of using include and required once()?

Tags: php

What is the difference between include and required_once()?
I want to include another php file let us consider as sample2.php in example1.php.Which is the best practice to use.

Comment: `_once` functions make sure that the file being called is only loaded one time, if that file happens to be included in another file that also needs it and is included in the first it won't load it again it'll just use the one it loaded previously.

Answer (score 0):

To put it in the simplest terms, your PHP page can still run with an `include` file not being retrieved, where as if it's a `required_once` and the file it's trying to get doesn't exist or is not in the right directory, the whole page will fail to load

There are more of these:

- `require_once`
- `require`
- `include`
- `include_once`

The `once` ones will only include the file once in the page if multiple times it is called, whereas the functions without `once` will call them as many times as they are in your code.